# How to add plone group members from script

Tags: plone

I tried to add a plone user from a script that I ran with "./bin/instance run myscript.py"

```
ipdb>app.Plone.portal_groups.addPrincipalToGroup('newuser', 'Administrators')
True
```

but when I check the web interface the user is not added to the group.

Although

```
ipdb>app.Plone.portal_groups.getGroupMembers('Administrators')
['newuser']
```

says otherwise.

When I run the same code in a normal plone instance (by opening a console with http://localhost:8080/Plone/ipdb) it works.

Do I have to commit the changes I made to ZODB or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to commit your transaction after doing all the changes

```
import transaction
# do some things
transaction.commit()
```